# Integrity Error in Django project (NOT NULL constraint failed)

Tags: python, django

I am making auctions site right now and when i try to set my boolean to True/False by clicking a button, i get this error:

> NOT NULL constraint failed: auctions_bid.bid_offer

It revealed after I added `listing.save()` to POST button

Here is the code:

`Views`:

```
if request.method == "POST":
            # listing.owner = bid_owner
            # listing.price = bid_offer
        listing.isActive = False
        listing.save()
```

Here is where i get error

```
    if request.method == "POST": #BID FORM
        new_bid = request.POST.get("new_bid")
        f = Bid(bid_offer = new_bid, listing_offer = listing, bid_owner = request.user)
        f.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(f'./{itemID}')
```

`Form` itself:

```
<form action = "{% url 'auctions:listing' itemID %}" method = "post">
        {% csrf_token %}
    {%if user.id == owner.id%}
        <input type = "submit" value = "Accept" id = "accept_bid">
    {% endif %}
    </form>
```

`Bid model`:

```
class Bid(models.Model):
    bid_offer = models.IntegerField()
    listing_offer = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = "listings", null = True)
    bid_owner= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

`Listing` Model:

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 64)
    description = models.CharField(max_length= 128)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'auctions/media/images')
    isActive = models.BooleanField(default= True, blank=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name="user")
    categories = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete = models.CASCADE, blank= True, null = True, related_name = "category", default = "None")
    price = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
```

When I removed listing.save() everything was ok, but boolean would not change

Comment: Make sure you have `new_bid` in `new_bid = request.POST.get("new_bid")`.

Comment: ```class bidForm(forms.Form):
    new_bid = forms.IntegerField(label = "Your offer")```

Comment: I mean make sure your are passing it in your post data.

Comment: sorry, yes i am passing all the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form doesn't seem to have a proper input field with the name "new_bid", so when you do `new_bid = request.POST.get("new_bid")` `new_bid` is NULL. Later when you try to save your new `Bid` object, it's `bid_offer` is null, and that's why you get the error.

Your form should include something like this
`<input type = "number" name="new_bid">`

OR

in your Bid model set  `bid_offer = models.IntegerField(null=True)`, if the bid_offer field is optional.

Comment: here is the error i get:     `super().__init__(**kwargs)
TypeError: Field.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'null'`

Comment: The line `bid_offer = models.IntegerField(null=True)` is meant to be in `class Bid(models.Model)` not in Form class.
And only if bid_offer is an optional field.